# TF401262: Value of long text field System.Description exceeds the maximum length allowed length of 1048576

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS 2017 update 1 (on premise install). When I try to paste a large number of HTML tables and lots of text into the Description field, I get the following error:
TF401262: Value of long text field System.Description exceeds the maximum length allowed length of 1048576.

Can I change this limit ?

Answer (score 1):

> I had the same kind of necessity, so I tried a little bit harder...

This is my tfs database (Tfs_Dev):

[image: database]

I executed this procedure to add a registry value in TFS configuration:

```
EXEC [dbo].[prc_SetRegistryValue] 
   @partitionId=1, 
   @key='#\Service\WorkItemTracking\Settings\MaxLongTextSize\', 
   @value='2000000000'
```

I could find this solution after looking in TFS source code, thanks to a great tool named [dnspy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy)

[image: dnspy]

You can find the specific TFS dll in a path similar to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 15.0\Application Tier\Web Services\bin\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.dll`

Answer (score 0):

Tested and cannot reproduce this issue on my side. But obviously it has the limitation for the maximum allowed length.

Generally String fields take a max of 255 characters. PlainText/HTML will take a max of 32K. If it crosses this limits, you can opt to store it to a file and add it as an attachment.

However you can try to change the limit by editing the `web.config` of the TFS site follow the instruction mentioned in this article : [Easy Ways to Upload and Validate Large Files in ASP.NET](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/upload-large-files-asp-net-radasyncupload)

> If you use IIS7 and you want to upload files larger than the
>   restricted 30000000 bytes or 28.6 MB, you can add the following code
>   to your web.config file in order to set that value to 100 MB:
>
> ```
> <system.webServer>
>     <security>
>         <requestFiltering>
>             <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
>         </requestFiltering>
>     </security>
> </system.webServer>
> ```

If that still not work then please share the steps to reproduce the issue, especially for the `"large number of HTML tables and lots of text"` you mentioned (You can store the strings in a file e.g `word` if it's too large then share the file in Onedrive or another  site we can access).

Comment: @Antonio De Vito Have you resolved the issue? Is the answer helpful? any update?